# python 2.6 - print French characters

Tags: python, python-2.6, non-ascii-characters

My question regarding printing French characters with python 2.6. 
There is no problems when I use python 3.4 but I need using python 2.6!
Instead of société mère I've got sociÃ©tÃ© mÃ¨re etc.
I already tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
```

without success.
I create a .csv file and need to fill headings with French titles. Also, some French characters will be input from .xml file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try prefixing your string literals with u:

```
print u'société mère'
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it did not work. 
When I try to print French characters from a string there is no problem. However, I have a LIST of strings (to use as headings in .csv excel file). So, I tried convert list to string and all French characters were displaying fine. Now I am trying to convert that string to a list with keeping French characters (without success so far). Maybe I should fill cells one-by-one?

Comment: @rvp In addition to declaring the encoding of the Python source file you should also see what encoding the input XML is in, what encoding you write the CSV into and how the CSV gets imported or read after that.